# rank of sum of random elements of Pauli group

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, involutions

The Pauli group for n-qubits is defined as $G_n=\{I,X,Y,Z\}⊗n$, that is as the group containing all the possible tensor products between $n$ Pauli matrices. I take the real version where $X=[[0,1],[1,0]]$,$Z=[[1,0],[0,-1]]$,$Y=XZ$. For any element $S_i$ of this group, $S_i^2=\pm I$. Now I take the sum of $m$ random elements of this group and calculate its rank. For $m$ even, there seems to be a definite distribution with full rank being the most probable. For $m$ odd, it seems that the sum is always full rank! This is surprising. Can anyone provide a theoretical explanation for these two cases. I think this might also generalize for random involutions.

Comment: Your result doesn't make sense. If $M \in G_n$ is a sum of $m$ elements that fails to have full rank, then $M \otimes I$ is a sum of $m$ elements of $G_{n+1}$ that fails to have full rank.

Comment: That doesn't contradict anything. tensoring by $I$ doesn't change the number of summands. Also $G_n$ is a group so all elements are full rank. The sum of elements is almost always outside the group even when invertible.

Comment: Sorry, I confused $m$ with $n$. Also, I misspoke: I meant to say that if $M$ is a sum of $m$ elements of $G_n$ (but not itself an element of $G_n$) such that $M$ fails to have full rank, then $M \otimes I$ is a sum of $m$ elements of $G_{n+1}$ that fails to have full rank.

Comment: One possible clue : the elements of $G_n$ have eigenvalues $\pm 1,\pm \imath$; for odd $m$ these can't be combined to produce $0$. So if the $S_i$'s commute, they can be simultaneously diagonalized and the resultant (diagonal) sum has no 0 entries, so full rank. However what I observe seems to be true regardless of whether the $S_i$'s commute; so there's probably a more general way to approach this.